# Adjoint of product of complex number and ket: Is $\left(z|\psi \rangle\right)^\dagger= z^* \langle \psi|$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, complex-numbers

Is $\left(z|\psi \rangle\right)^\dagger= z^* \langle \psi|$ ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Have you tried to work this out using the linear algebra rules?

Comment: Can we state that (z|ψ>)+ = (|ψ>)^+(z)*=<ψ|(z)*=(z)*<ψ|

Comment: Yes. That's it. Do you want to post this as an answer to your own question? 

Also, you can make your equations look better by using MathJax properly. So I'd write what you have written as $ \left(z |\psi \rangle\right)^\dagger = z^\dagger |\psi \rangle^\dagger = z^* \langle \psi |$ --the thing I put inside the $$ is  \left(z |\psi \rangle\right)^\dagger = z^\dagger |\psi \rangle^\dagger = z^* \langle \psi |.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct (so long as $z$ is a scalar complex number, and not an operator, if course).

Comment: Just for completeness: if it were an operator it is easy to generalise its action to bras: $(\hat{O} |\psi\rangle )^\dagger = \langle{\psi} |\hat{O}^\dagger$